# Python splitting function and storing values

Tags: python, split

I have a txt file that reads as follows:

```
math,89
history,90
history,94
```

I am trying to split each line so I can convert the the numbers to integers and use the numbers to find the average grade.  I am having issues with splitting the string at the ' , ' and storing the 2 parts I split into 2 different variables.

Here is the main part of the code that i think is the issue:

```
def main():

total = 0
count = 0

myfile = open('grades.txt','r')

for line in myfile:
    array = line.split(",")
    course = array[0]
    amount = float(array[1])
    total += amount

myfile.close()
```

Sorry forgot to add the error I am getting: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: Nope, the code seems fine. Please add the error traceback in your question.

Comment: `total += int(amount)` or `total += [amount]`

Comment: what issues ? Always add full error message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: Nothing stands out that would throw an error. Maybe some more context (like how `total` is defined and used to average). Side note: you might want to use Python's tuple unwrapping to get the two values out of your lines: `course, grade = line.split(",")`.

Comment: yes sorry I will add the full code:

Comment: By "traceback", people mean not only the error message itself, but also the part where python says what was being executed, with a succession of calls together with line numbers

Comment: Do you use `myfile` later in your code?

Comment: Other hypothesis: your actual code may have an indentation problem whereby you close the file inside the for loop.

Comment: 1)now the code's plain illegal Python. 2)full traceback please